# plotly.graph_objects is saving old info

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I have created a graph in python utilizing the follow sample code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

image_path = "C:/Users/Me/Pictures/x.png"

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(...))

fig.write_image(image_path)
```

When I go to create new image with this same code, the old data is still in there somewhere and saves with the old data rather than the new data.

I tried using `fig.close()` but I get an error `'Figure' object has no attribute 'close'`.  I also tried using `plt.close('all')` but no luck.

I tried looking on the [ploty.graph_objects](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.html#module-plotly.graph_objects) page but was not able to find how to close the image or save new image with new data.

I also tried clearing the figure data/layout after each run with `fig.data = []` and `fig.layout = {}`

I also tried `fig.show()` which when looping through images, does show the correct image but the saved image still shows old data.

Any ideas on how to save a figure graph object from plotly with new data?

Comment: Why are you mixing matplotlib and plotly?

Answer (score 0):

- generating four indicators in a loop
- save to a filename *x.png* and *x_.png*
- *x.png* and *x_750.png* are the same so file is definitely being overwritten

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd().joinpath("indicator_images")
if not p.is_dir():
    p.mkdir()

for v in [300,450,600,750]:
    fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = v,
        title = {'text': "Speed"},
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}
    ))
    fig.write_image(p.joinpath("x.png"))
    fig.write_image(p.joinpath(f"x_{v}.png"))
```